# Multiple select statements in a single query

Tags: sql

The total number should be the sum of ShipperIDs. This is the code I have so far, but I see all 1s for the columns.
If you look at it, the numbers for number3, 2, 1 columns don't add up to the total number and only shows a bunch of 1s.

```
SELECT 
OrderDate,
COUNT(OrderID) AS totalID, 
(SELECT COUNT(ShipperID) FROM Orders WHERE ShipperID='3' GROUP BY OrderDate) AS number3, 
(SELECT COUNT(ShipperID) FROM Orders WHERE ShipperID='2' GROUP BY OrderDate) AS number2, 
(SELECT COUNT(ShipperID) FROM Orders WHERE ShipperID='1' GROUP BY OrderDate) AS number1
FROM Orders 
WHERE OrderDate >= '1996-07-04' 
GROUP BY OrderDate 
ORDER BY OrderDate ASC;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_count

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UUo9.png)

Comment: You should tag the RDBMS you are using - just no others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for these multiple subqueries. You can scan the table only once, and then use conditional expressions inside the aggregate functions:

```
SELECT case_start_date_time AS eventdatetime, COUNT(*) AS total_riskid, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_details_analyst_action = 'PASS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as pass_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_details_analyst_action = 'FAIL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as fail_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_details_analyst_action = 'REINSTATE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as reinstate_count
FROM lz.risk_rcm_ato_flattened
WHERE eventdatetime >= '2020-12-01'
GROUP BY case_start_date_time
```